# What exactly is a JavaScript pragma?

Tags: javascript

When you want a JavaScript file (or function) to be parsed in "strict mode" you can put..

```
"use strict";
```

..in the top of your JavaScript file (or function).

This "use strict"; is a so-called "pragma".

My question: **what exactly is a pragma?**
The closest thing I can think of is a "directive".

Comment: I assume it was named after C [`pragma`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) preprocessor directive.

Comment: @VisioN I think this line out of the page you linked was quite clear: "The `#pragma' directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> compiler directives are called pragmas (short for "pragmatic information").

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor_directive

It's a pre-processor directive, or like code metadata. It's similar to other languages or compilers that use stuff like this more.  It's pragmatic information about how to interpret the code that follows.

And as far as I know, this is the only one in JavaScript. It's sort of a hack to force modern interpreters to behave in a certain way, but without breaking older interpreters.

Comment: Does `debugger;` count as a pragma?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd say no.  I believe `debugger` a keyword.  It doesn't describe how to execute other code, it simply does something when executed, like any other keyword.

Comment: @JanDvorak it's usually referred to as a "statement." I think "use strict" is a "pragma" because it's not interpreted in-line, while `debugger` is.

Comment: It certainly is [not the only one in JavaScript](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-2002-04/core/pragmas.html).

Comment: @EliranMalka It is today. After finding a copy of your archived in the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170331010050/https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-2002-04/core/pragmas.html), I can honestly say a draft spec for JavaScript 2.0 dated April 2002 has very little of modern relevance. =) Particularly since none of those pragmas have even been heard of by many today, sans `use strict`.

Answer (score 5):

> ⚡️*Pragma* is short for pragmatic information. In plain English, pragmatic is an adjective that means sensible and practical. In programming, *pragma* refers to the code that consist of useful information on **how a compiler or interpreter or assembler should process the program**.

It does not contribute anything to the programming language itself and its syntax may vary. They only affect the compiler behavior. JavaScript also has few pragmas, one of them is `strict`.

```
'use strict';
```

By the above pragma, the JavaScript code will be executed in strict mode. In strict mode, bad syntax isn't allowed, *hoisting* isn't 
done, silent errors are shown, etc. It helps in **writing a more secure and optimized JavaScript code**.